# How can I list all variables from stdin in for loop?

Tags: shell, shell-script

Having this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $#; do echo ${$i}; done
```

where `$#` should be number of vars from stdin,
gives:

```
${$i}: bad substitution
```

How to list them without having to write `echo $0; echo $1; echo ...`
And how to substitute variable itself in variable? (That is "building" var names by e.g. loop)

Comment: stdin != positional parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

argv[] is not stdin.

The *usual* way is to avoid indexing entirely and iterate over the *values* directly (basically, how `for..in` is supposed to work in the first place). The special "array" variable representing all arguments is `"$@"` – yes, the quotes are necessary for array expansion to happen correctly:

```bash
for v in "$@"; do
    echo "Got $v"
done
```

(Don't do this with `$*` nor with unquoted `$@` as both will mess up args containing spaces.)

However, if you *do* need indexes as well, the correct "dereference" syntax in bash is `${!i}`:

```bash
for (( i = 1; i <= $#; i++ )); do
    echo "Item $i is ${!i}"
done
```

(Note the C-like syntax needed to iterate over a numeric range. While it's possible to do *static* ranges using `for i in {1..10}` that unfortunately doesn't work when variables like `{1..$#}` start getting involved. But you can use `for i in $(seq 1 $#)` if you don't mind the extra subprocess.)

Finally, one of the oldest methods is to repeatedly `shift` the list of arguments:

```bash
while [ "${1+yes}" ]; do
    echo "Got $1"
    shift
done
```

The `${var+string}` expansion is used to check whether the variable is *set to anything*, instead of checking for non-zero-length strings. You might sometimes see this simplified to a more direct check – which is fine as long as you're 100% sure there won't be any zero-length args:

```bash
while [ "$1" ]; do
    echo "Got $1"
    shift
done
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$@"; do echo "${i}"; done
```

Example:

```
$ ./s.sh a b c 'white space'
a
b
c
white space
```